# many to many mapping in Grails

Tags: grails

devices :[1.1:Acer C6, 2:Acer C6, 1:Acer C6, 2.2:HTC Magic]
files :[2:Tetris.apk, 1:TheSims3.apk]

I have a mapping of files and devies, as of now its one-to-many mapping.

devices :[1.1:Acer C6, 2:Acer C6, 1:Acer C6, 2.2:HTC Magic]
files :[2:Tetris.apk, 1:TheSims3.apk]

Now I need to implement many-to-many mapping

my logic for one-to-many mapping is

```
mapping = params.devices.inject( [:] ) { map, dev ->
          // Get the first part of the version (up to the first dot)
          def v = dev.key.split( /\./ )[ 0 ]
            logger.debug("value of v :"+v)
          map << [ (dev.value): files[ v ] ]

        }
```

current output is -     mapping :[Acer C6:Tetris.apk, HTC Magic:Tetris.apk]

expected output : [Acer C6:Tetris.apk, Acer C6:TheSims3.apk, HTC Magic:Tetris.apk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accumulating your results using the device name as a key.  When a new value is added to the map, it overwrites the last one with the same key.

You could try accumulating into a Set instead of a map.  Example:

```
def devices = ['1.1': 'Acer C6', '2': 'Acer C6', '1': 'Acer C6', '2.2': 'HTC Magic']
def files = ['2': 'Tetris.apk', '1': 'TheSims3.apk']

def deviceFiles = devices.inject([] as Set) { deviceFiles, device ->
    def v = device.key.split( /\./ )[0]
    deviceFiles << [ (device.value), files[ v ] ]
}

assert deviceFiles == [
    ['Acer C6', 'Tetris.apk'], 
    ['Acer C6', 'TheSims3.apk'], 
    ['HTC Magic', 'Tetris.apk']
] as Set
```

Comment: Hi, in the following pages of this logic, i have used properties and that has to be unchanged, could you please let me know the better way of handling this set to be converted to a map?